# How to compare two mediation models?

Tags: spss, mediation

I ran a mediation study using three dispositional measures, each measured with a scale. The order of scales was in line with my assumed model, so **A --> B --> C**. 
Using SPSS and PROCESS the results support the notion that B mediates the association of A --> C and there seems to be full mediation. 
Now, to protect this finding against possible criticism I also tested an alternative mediation model using the exact same scales but in a different order: **A --> C --> B**. Also this model looks good but there is not full mediation. 
I would like to compare these two models but I am puzzled how to do that. I found two suggested approaches by Mackinnon & Dwyer (1993). 
A) refer to the total effect that is mediated
B) refer to the ratio of the indirect to direct effect.
For B) PROCESS already provides the numbers:

Model 1

```
Ratio of indirect to direct effect of X on Y
            Effect    Boot SE   BootLLCI   BootULCI
mean_SCC   -16,6985    88,0316 -2091,0335    -8,2910
```

Model 2

```
Ratio of indirect to direct effect of X on Y
             Effect    Boot SE   BootLLCI   BootULCI
mean_INC      ,0975      ,0467      ,0164      ,2032
```

The numbers are  pretty different (I guess they are unstandardized) and I am wondering whether I can use them to make the comparison of interest. What do you think?

Alternatively, do I have to justify/compare at all?